# How to open GooglePhoto's video/image by Uri link?

Tags: android

I pick a video from Google Photos app, using:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
     MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(intent, PLAY_VIDEO);
```

and on `ActivityResult` I get the following uri:

```
content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/2/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fvideo%2Fmedia%2F86/ORIGINAL/NONE/video%2Fmp4/1871297128
```

Then I try to open the same video in Google Photos by given link, through:

```
Intent configIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, link);
startActivity(configIntent);
```

But the only thing I get is the toast message: "Media not found".
Why? Maybe I need to specify some extras to opening intent?

Comment: Is your second code snippet in the same activity instance as the first code snippet? Your rights to access the content identified by the `Uri` [are time-limited](https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/08/08/uri-access-lifetime-still-shorter-than-you-might-think.html).

Comment: Yes. Add a flag grant read uri permission to intent.

Comment: @CommonsWare, no, it's in the different activity :( Now I understand